# Check a number included in nested number array contains range in PHP

Tags: php, algorithm

I have nested number array like this: `[ [ 0, 100 ], [ 300, 500 ] ]`

And I needed check given number in any range of that array.

Array format is: `[ start, end ]`

For example, If the given number is `30`, That included in `$array[0]`, but `200` not included in any range. So `30` is `true`, but `200` is `false`.

Yes, I can check this using for-loop. But I think there available better method to check this maybe. However I am weak at algorithm, so I tried found solution at Google and StackOverflow but nothing found.

Maybe there available answer of this problem already, But I couldn't found solution about this problem. If there answer already available sorry for duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_filter` to filter the valid ranges.

This should do the trick...

```
<?php

$arr = [ [ 0, 100 ], [ 300, 500 ] ];

function in_range($value, $arr) {
  $valid_ranges = array_filter($arr, function($range) use ($value) {
    return $value >= $range[0] && $value <= $range[1];
  });

  return count($valid_ranges) > 0;
}

echo in_range(30,$arr) ? 'yes' : 'no';
echo PHP_EOL;
echo in_range(200,$arr) ? 'yes' : 'no';
echo PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a small function that does what you want by looping on an array of ranges and checking it's min and max. If passed, it will early return to `true` and if all checks fails, it will return `false`.

```
function isInRange($input) {
    $ranges = [[0, 100], [300, 500]];
    foreach ($ranges as $range) {
        if (($range[0] <= $input) && ($input <= $range[1])) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

var_dump(isInRange(30)); // true
var_dump(isInRange(200)); // false
```

What I did was just utilize this expression:

```
($min <= $value) && ($value <= $max)
```

will be true if $value is between $min and $max, inclusively and just incorporated the `$min` and `$max` in the loop.